# Каким элементам в css, при верстке можно не присваивать класс?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, бэм, frontend

Как понять когда стоит задать имя класса элементу, а когда можно обойтись простой конструкцией "родитель элемент{}"

**Пример**:

```
<div class="block">
 <p>Текст</p>
</div> 

.block p{
  color:red
 }
```

**Пример 2:**

```
<div class="block">
 <p class="block__text">Текст</p>
</div> 

.block__text{
 color:red;
 }
```

Я понимаю, что оба варианта будут работать одинаково, но не понимаю, как писать правильней.

Comment: У вас в тегах указан "БЭМ", а там пишут вот `В CSS по БЭМ также не рекомендуется использовать селекторы по тегам или id.`

Answer (score 1):

В комментарии правильно сказали, что как удобно так и пиши.

Но если хочется рекомендации, эти рекомендации лично от меня)

Если я выполняю простые работы которые в дальнейшем будут обновляться, переписываться, лично мне удобно писать так, что я присваиваю каждому блоку класс. Структура блоков выглядит примерно так:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__inner">
        <div class="header__logo"></div>
        <div class="header__title"></div>
        <div class="header__sub-title"></div>
    </div>
</header>

<section id="about">
    <div class="about__inner">
        <div class="about__left-block"></div>
        <div class="about__right-block"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Мне удобен такой способ, так как я имею контроль над каждый элементом, я стараюсь называть максимально ясно, в зависимости что в этом блоке находится.

**Так же.**

Вы можете писать блоки без классов и потом обращаться к ним через родительский элемент. Я тоже так делаю когда выполняю мелкие работы, где я точно не запутаюсь если вернусь к верстке через месяц.

```
<section id="list">
    <div class="list__inner">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>  

<style>
    .list__inner > ul > li {
        color: #000000;
    } 
</style>
```

Но хочу предупредить, что если у вас будет много контента, вам нужно строго разделять файлы стилей, если все будет в одном вы можете запутаться.

**И еще:**

Вы можете использовать Gulp, препроцессоры scss. Настоятельно рекомендую изучить препроцессоры. Если начнете. в этом разбираться можете воспользоваться мои конфигом https://github.com/MaxWatson94/Gulp